# How Deserialize JSON array objects that have no name/label

Tags: .net, json

The JSON String below is provided from an api of a software we use. I do not have control on how the JSON is formatted so this is what I have to work with. I am having issues with the below JSON String on getting the class structure setup correctly. Below will be a few examples of code I have attempted. Any help would be much appreciated.

The specific area I am having issues with is the group_access object. I believe these are an array of integers. I attempted converting it to a list, 
`Public Property group_access As List(Of List(Of Array))`.

I also attempted giving the object its own class

`Public Property group_access As GroupAccess`

```
   Public Class GroupAccess
       Public Property Result As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of List(Of Integer)))
   End Class
```

JSON data:

```html
{""type"":""users"",""limit"":1,""offset"":0,""total"":440,""time"":""0.029s"",""items"":[{""id"":170336,""email"":""tina.doe@email.org"",""fname"":""Tina"",""full_name"":""Tina Doe"",""grades"":[],""group_access"":{""27913"":2,""27898"":0,""28014"":0,""27934"":0},""last_login"":""2019-04-04
20:51:49"",""lname"":""Doe"",""resource_id"":""O97I0G5BU"",""roles"":{""27913"":{""2017"":2,""2018"":2},""27898"":{""2017"":0,""2018"":0},""28014"":{""2018"":0},""27934"":{""2017"":0,""2018"":0}},""tags"":[""AZ - Maryvale"",""Arizona""],""title"":"""",""inactive_group_ids"":[27934],""active"":true,""targets"":[""Leader
Development Target""],""caseload_tags"":[]}],""items_count"":1}
```

Class Data:

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property email As String
    Public Property fname As String
    Public Property lname As String
    Public Property full_name As String
    Public Property resource_id As String
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property tags As IList(Of String)
    Public Property grades As IList(Of String)
    Public Property targets As IList(Of String)
    Public Property group_access As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of List(Of Double)))
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property limit As Integer
    Public Property offset As Integer
    Public Property total As Integer
    Public Property time As String
    Public Property items As List(Of Item)
    Public Property items_count As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Did you try with just a `Dictionary(Of String, Double)` ?

Comment: @Kalten Thank you! that was it. Something so simple was right in front of me. Please leave this as answer and I will give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your json payload, the `group_access` object look like a simple dictionary. So the corresponding type should be something like :

```
Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
```

Final classes :

```
Public Class Item
    // ...
    Public Property group_access As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
    // ...
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    // ...
    Public Property items As List(Of Item)
    // ...
End Class
```